# Unofficial Google data science blog problem application

Tags: modeling, causality

**Problem description:** Every 3 weeks a fashion company sends out an expensive booklet with descriptions of clothes to each customer from the company's electronic records. There exists a purchase history what each customer bought in the 3 weeks after receiving the booklet and pricing information about clothes. *The problem is to find those customers to whom it makes sense to send the booklet, so that fewer booklets are sent.*
Additionally to this data, there is also a small dataset containing information what customers bought in a period of 9 weeks when no booklet was sent out.
I cannot change this data, this is all I got and I need to work with what I have.

A more detailed description can be found [here](http://Problem%20description:%20Every%203%20weeks%20a%20fashion%20company%20sends%20out%20an%20expensive%20booklet%20with%20descriptions%20of%20clothes%20to%20each%20customer%20on%20their%20electronic%20records.%20There%20exists%20a%20purchase%20history%20what%20each%20customer%20bought%20in%20the%203%20weeks%20after%20receiving%20the%20booklet%20and%20pricing%20information%20about%20clothes.%20The%20problem%20is%20to%20find%20those%20customers%20to%20whom%20it%20makes%20sense%20to%20send%20the%20booklet,%20so%20that%20fewer%20booklets%20are%20sent.%20Additionally%20to%20this%20data,%20there%20is%20also%20a%20small%20dataset%20containing%20information%20what%20customers%20bought%20in%20a%20period%20of%209%20weeks%20when%20no%20booklet%20was%20sent%20out.).

I can hypothetically
 imagine a variety of different models that output some selection of customers that the model thinks will be customers that will buy lots of things when they receive such a booklet. **But the problem is that to train them, for each of these models I need to somehow assess (some variant of) the spending history of those customer that did not receive any booklet, so that I will can use this information as a feature.

    Q1: How can I do that assessment, given my fixed dataset?**

(The only way I could address this would be to make various assumptions when the booklet had no influence (such as "if product X was not in the past 5 booklets and during this time 70% of all the people bought X, when a customer at current time buys X, it should be considered to be bought as if no booklet had been sent out"), and hope that they were good, since I have almost no way to test them, since my dataset from which I need to come up with a model is fixed.
I was given a hint by seanv507 that the **[unofficial Google data sicence blog](http://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2017/01/causality-in-machine-learning.html#)** might contain information how I actually might be able to test such assumption; unfortunately the section "Using randomization in training" which is the interesting part telling me how to do that, was a bit too vague and at the same time to technical for me to make much sense of it.)
**Q2: Could you let me know if what is in that blog is relevant to my problem - and if yes how to apply it?**